# Can python load all files in all subfolders without the complete names?

Tags: python, file-upload, deep-learning, image-classification

Please Help me.
I'm new to python and I want to load all jpg images in 500 folders (each folder has up to 100 jpg images).
I also have a CSV file that contains labels for folders, I want to tell python to consider every folder label for all jpg images in that folder.

example file name: folder_name[.....].jpg

Each file has the same folder name, except the [], which is different for each file.
How can I tell python no matter what it is  []??

I would appreciate any help.

```
train = pd.read_csv("COAD_CMS_label_train.csv")` 
train_image = []
for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img('tiles/'+train['folder_name'][i]+' [*]'.astype('str')+'.jpg', target_size=(256,256,3), 
                         grayscale=False,)
```

example for labels:

folder_name,Label

TCGA-A6-2683-01Z-00-DX1.0dfc5d0a-68f4-45e1-a879-0428313c6dbc,CMS2

TCGA-F4-6459-01Z-00-DX1.80a78213-1137-4521-9d60-ac64813dec4c,CMS4

TCGA-A6-6653-01Z-00-DX1.e130666d-2681-4382-9e7a-4a4d27cb77a4,CMS1

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this which will result in an array of all files with the jpg extension, where parent_dir is the parent directory which contains all the subdirectories with the images.

```
images_files = glob.iglob(f'{parent_dir}/*.jpg', recursive=True)
```

Hope that helps.

Good luck